# GCP Routing for Kube Master Node

Tags: networking, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, routes, google-cloud-networking

Is there a way to apply a route to the master nodes on the network 172.16.0.16/28 in GCP? I need traffic with the destination of 100.64.0.0/11 and 100.96.0.0/11 to be forwarded through a specific instance for OpenVPN Connect.

Currently we have routes setup for these destinations for the main project network, and that seems to forward all traffic on say 10.0.0.0/8 to the connector as expected, but we can't get kubectl to connect from local machines to the master node at 172.16.0.XX, the traffic drops.

Anyone worked with this before and have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to add routes to the Master Node.

If your cluster is private maybe you should add the 172.16.0.XX range as a [master authorized networks](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/private-clusters#endpoints) in order to reach the master node.

If is public you should check the firewall rules and see if there is anyone which might be blocking the 172.16.0.XX range.

Comment: Thanks, but we did find a way to add routes to the master cluster using export-custom-routes.

https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/private-clusters#cp-on-prem-routing